# What determines whether or not I become the Squad Leader of a given Squad?

Tags: battlefield-3

Sometimes when playing Battlefield 3 I wish that I could force myself to become the squad leader/start a new squad in a given situation, so that people could spawn on me(as I understand it, you can only spawn on squad leaders...is this wrong?) and use my advantageous position(for example, when flanking the enemy). However, I still have absolutely no idea if it's even possible to "make" a new squad mid-battle and what determines whether or not I become a squad leader. Any idea what causes this to happen?

Comment: You are able to spawn on any squad member. Only the squad leader can issue orders though.

Comment: @Albort Hm, but I can't spawn on every person on the map. What determines which people can be spawned on?

Comment: Some servers limit you to only be able to spawn on your squad leader, some do not.

Comment: You will only be able to spawn on someone if they are in your squad, alive and not in water

Comment: @Albort: ...and not falling/parachuting/in a full vehicle/in a very small area/off the edge of the map

Answer (score 2):

As far as I have been able to work out, being assigned to the position of squad leader is a case of "first in". When you join a squad, you may notice that there is an order to it. If someone higher up than you then leaves the squad, everyone lower moves up a space. In this fashion, you can only become squad leader if you are in the second position and the squad leader leaves (you will be notified with a big heads-up "You are now the Squad Leader" notice).

Edit: It is possible to make a squad mid-battle.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be random or skill/rank based. Many times I'll be the forth person to join a squad, and if the leader leaves, I become the new squad leader.

Comment: I've also had glitched-out things happen, like I'll join a squad that already has a leader, but I'll be made a leader also. I can't see the other leader in the squad management screen, but I can spawn on him, and the same goes for him. Somehow this causes the player limit to break, and I've had up to 8 people in a squad before.

Comment: @MrSmooth yeah I thought it might be rank based, that wasn't true, then I thought it was "in order of join" now I am not sure that's true either. Seems to be random?

Comment: Round points maybe at the time the current leader leaves?