# Why is there sometimes no squad leader?

Tags: battlefield-3

Several times I've been in a squad with no one marked as squad leader, i.e., there's no star next to the name at the top of the squad list.  According to previous questions ([one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33692/what-determines-whether-or-not-i-become-the-squad-leader-of-a-given-squad), [two](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33281/battlefield-3-squad-management), [three](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33631/what-is-the-significance-of-the-star-next-to-your-name-in-the-squad-list)) the SL should be assigned automatically.

At first I assumed this was a server setting. But today I saw it happen inconsistently: on the same server and map, at one point there was no leader, and at another point there was.

Does anyone know what's happening? My theories:

1. **Display glitch.** The top person actually is the SL but just doesn't appear that way. However, I'm 95% sure I was in this situation once when I was at the top of the squad list, and yet I was unable to set objectives.
2. **Server setting.** There's server setting I don't understand, for example, a delay in appointing the SL.
3. **Volunteer leaders.** There's some way for people to request assignment as a SL. I wish this were true, but previous questions suggest it's not.

Comment: I just had it happen as well. I was list first in the squad but didn't have the star and I couldn't assign objectives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug, and not a display bug, there actually is no squad leader in your squad.

I'm not sure, but I think if you leave and then rejoin the squad, it should update. Will have to test next time this bug happens.

Comment: Thanks for the tip that leaving and rejoining might fix it. I'll try that next time. Either way, accepted answer.